# how to disable the telnet in vxworks

Tags: vxworks

I am very new to this vxwork operatng system.

Can some one please let me know on how to disable the telnet service on vxworks6.4.

Is there is any command to disable the telnet service on the Vxworks 6.4

Answer (score 2):

If you want to disable telent server at runtime,

```
ipcom_run_cmd("ipd kill iptelnets"); /* in the c code */

-> ipcom_run_cmd "ipd kill iptelnets" /* in the C interpreter */

-> cmd
[vxWorks]# ipd kill iptelnets /* in the cmd interpreter */
```

If you want to disable telnet server at compile time,

```
$ vxprj component remove INCLUDE_IPTELNETS
```

Answer (score 1):

In your vxworks6.4.libcurl.config.h add (or uncomment)

```
define CURL_DISABLE_TELNET 1
```

For its references check here:
http://code.metager.de/source/s?refs=CURL_DISABLE_TELNET&project=curl

Comment: will this flag is persistance ? i.e when the system reboots will this still retains

Comment: I have not tried that, but I dont see any reason for it to vanish if its defined in the config file? `curl/lib/config-vxworks.h`

Comment: dynamic enabling and disabling of telnet rebooting is not possible with the above changes, is there any other way to perform this action ?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to permanently disable telnet you could try suspending the telnet task using the functions `taskSuspend` and `taskResume`.

...I know it's dirty...